# C# Logical memory configuration view

Tags: c#, memory

How can view logical memory configuration ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectQuery winQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(winQuery);
        foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
        {
            textBox1.Text =("Total Space = " + item["TotalPageFileSpace"]);
            textBox2.Text = ("Total Physical Memory = " + item["TotalPhysicalMemory"]);
            textBox3.Text = ("Total Virtual Memory = " + item["TotalVirtualMemory"]);
            textBox4.Text = ("Available Virtual Memory = " + item["AvailableVirtualMemory"]);
        }
    }
```

In this code seems doesn't work . And has no error on compilation .

Comment: What does it display when you run it?

Comment: Nothing ! Without exception !

Answer (score 4):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration WMI class is no longer available for use as of Windows Vista.

The article suggests you use the `Win32_OperatingSystem` but you might be better off using  `Process.GetCurrentProcess()`.